# CakePHP: Using a join table on non-HABTM relationship

Tags: mysql, cakephp, database-schema, belongs-to, join

I have a relation represented in MySQL that is

```
Classified belongsTo Category
Category hasMany Classifieds
```

Previously, I have had `Classified.category_id` set, but some Classifieds do not have Categories, and many Categories do not have any ads.  This relationship is optional.

I have normalized the database to represent the database in a third table, categories_classifieds.

```
categories_classifieds
----
classified_id (primary, not null)
category_id (not null)
```

The reason this was normalized this way is to avoid null values, and also to

I am trying to create Models for the database in CakePHP 2, and there does not seem to be support for this simple relationship.  Is this possible? Does the `categories_classifieds` join table need to be made into its own Model?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Here are crow's-feet notation ER diagrams of the current, and proposed schemas: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BBVV.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is a [**hasAndBelongsToMany**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) relation.

Make sure to follow cake's conventions though and make a seperate `id` field as primary key for the connecting model. You may not even need to have a model created for it and let it all to automagic after building the necessary relations in the models.

Comment: There won't be a problem with the cardinality matches between CakePHP and MySQL?  MySQL won't tolerate a key violation, but I don't want problematic key violation errors displayed to the end user...

Comment: This is a basic relation in cake so almost everybody is using it and it works fine. There can't be any key violations if you set up your models and DB right, just follow the conventions and common sense. For example if you delete a `Category` it is obvious all corresponding rows from the interconnecting table need to go too. This can be done by Cake in the `Category::beforeDelete()` callback or by MySQL (you need to set `CASCADE` if I remember correctly) or both (so if you miss something in the business logic the DB will take care of it). I personally let it to the DB to handle.